# Node.js and express returns response without code status

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wrote a server in `node.js`, using `Express`.

I use the express log, and everything works great. Here is a log example:

```
x.x.x.x - - [Thu, 13 Nov 2014 15:10:55 GMT] "POST /fileExists HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Java/1.6.0_45"
x.x.x.x - - [Thu, 13 Nov 2014 15:10:55 GMT] "POST /fileExists HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Java/1.6.0_45"
x.x.x.x - - [Thu, 13 Nov 2014 15:10:55 GMT] "POST /fileExists HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Java/1.6.0_45"
x.x.x.x - - [Thu, 13 Nov 2014 15:10:55 GMT] "POST /fileExists HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Java/1.6.0_45"
x.x.x.x - - [Thu, 13 Nov 2014 15:10:55 GMT] "POST /fileExists HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Java/1.6.0_45"
```

In some point, for some reason, Express stops to response with status code, and I get the following:

```
x.x.x.x - - [Thu, 13 Nov 2014 11:04:05 GMT] "POST /fileExists HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Java/1.6.0_45"
x.x.x.x - - [Thu, 13 Nov 2014 11:04:05 GMT] "POST /fileExists HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Java/1.6.0_45"
x.x.x.x - - [Thu, 13 Nov 2014 11:04:05 GMT] "POST /fileExists HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Java/1.6.0_45"
x.x.x.x - - [Thu, 13 Nov 2014 11:04:05 GMT] "POST /fileExists HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Java/1.6.0_45"
x.x.x.x - - [Thu, 13 Nov 2014 11:04:05 GMT] "POST /fileExists HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Java/1.6.0_45"
```

Just after I restart my application, Express returns to response as usual.

**EDIT:**

My server using many modules, and it a complicated one.

Here are some parts of my application:

```
var app = express();
....
app.post("/fileExists", function (req, res) {
     var guid = req.body.guid;
     var name = req.body.fileName;
     // Some code using aws-s3 component (Amazon s3 service..). err variable is the indicate if error occurred
     if (err != null)
        FS.prototype.returnResCode(res, "404");
     else 
        FS.prototype.returnResCode(res, "200");
})

FS.prototype.returnResCode = function (res, err) {
    if (err != "200") {
        res.writeHead(err, {'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        var objToJson = JSON.stringify(errorCode[err]);
        res.end(objToJson);
    }
}
```

What can be the reason for this beaver?

Comment: way more detail needed

Comment: @MaxBumaye I edited the question, and add some code. If there is any more relevant code which needed,  please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Sobiaholic I edited the question, and add some code. If there is any more relevant code which needed, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: looking at your logic it should always return either 200 or 404... at some point you must be writing to your log without giving it a status code... I cant see this in your excerpt :/

Comment: @MaxBumaye: What? This is the express log, not my log. My application returns always 200 or 404, until some point when Express decided to return response without status code..

Comment: where are you responding to requests that execute the `FS.prototype.returnResCode(res, "200")`?